# Need explanation of below Negative LookBehind

Tags: perl

```
$string2 = '<tag id="123">123</tag>';

$string2 =~ s/123(?![^><]*>)/456/cg;
```

I need an explanation about negative lookbehind pattern `(?![^><]*>)` in the above code.

Comment: I like https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html for explanations of lookarounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you have is trying to replace the text inside a tag without interfering with the tag itself. There are better ways to do this, and I typically reach for [Mojo::DOM](https://docs.mojolicious.org/Mojo/DOM):

```
use v5.10;
use Mojo::DOM;

my $dom = Mojo::DOM->new('<tag id="123">123</tag>');
$dom->at( 'tag' )->child_nodes->[0]->replace( '456' );

say $dom;
```

This way, you don't have to think about any of the complexity of HTML or XML when you want to modify it. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/4234491/2766176 for fun.

Answer (score 6):

This is a negative lookahead, not a lookbehind. It asserts that the following characters do not match the pattern inside the lookahead.

In this case, `(?![^><]*>)` means "only match 123 if it is not followed by `>`, optionally with other characters except `>` or `<` in between".

So this regex will match:

- `123` alone
- `123` followed by other characters except `>`
- `123` followed by `<` but not `>`

But it will NOT match `123` followed by `>`, even with other characters in between. So for example:

- `123a` -> will match and replace
- `123<` -> will match and replace
- `123b>` -> will NOT match

The `[^><]*` part matches any number of characters except `>` or `<`.
The `>` part then asserts that the following character must NOT be `>`, otherwise it doesn't match.